Seeking Guidance on Synchronizing Indexing Data Between Two Solr Cloud Clusters in Different Regions(east us & central us)
I'm currently working with two Solr Cloud clusters located in different regions with Sitecore multi-region CDs, and I'm looking for advice on how to synchronize the indexing data between both Solr cluster. Can anyone help me identify the best approach for achieving this synchronization?
Thanks in Advance.
Any help is Appreciated.

What options have you looked at so far? What are your concerns about the various approaches? Do you have specific requirements regarding latency, data consistency, failover strategy, or monitoring / alerts? Have you looked into CDCR (Cross Data Center Replication)?  https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/cross-data-center-replication-cdcr.html

I've looked into both the backup/restore option and CDCR for syncing data between Solr clusters, but neither approach is working for me.
CDCR is deprecated and requires both clusters' ZooKeeper IPs to communicate with each other, which isn't feasible in my setup.
The backup and restore method also isn't viable, as it requires a common shared drive accessible by both clusters. My research indicates that this method doesn't work with a blob storage account.

You can setup multiple publishing database targets (e.g. web-datacentre1, web-datacentre2). The content delivery role in each data centre uses the corresponding database targets. The solr cloud in each data centre is connected to the corresponding database target. Publishing to the database target would then perform the normal index operation.

Thanks Vincent - Are you talking about this - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--replicating-the-web-database-using-azure-active-geo-replication.html

Correct. However, the documentation does not include detail on Solr Index.

Having two publishing targets can increase the latency. also, I am not sure I followed your point - "The solr cloud in each data center is connected to the corresponding database target. " could you please elaborate on it more?

Actually, I am gong to take that back. If you follow Sitecore's documentation, and then engage with SearchStax to setup a multi-region setup, then it should achieve what you need.
https://www.searchstax.com/managed-solr/solr-multi-cloud/

I think the goal is to setup Solrcloud and replication in house
